# Kenmore 465 Stove / Range with range missing a pipe and insulation exposed?

Tags: electrical, insulation, stove, range

I have a Kenmore stove that's probably from either 2006 or the 90s some time; and we recently replaced all the drip pans in it; I don't know why or who, but one family members pulled a pipe out of the bottom of the back left range and lost the pipe; it's the only range that has this; however the pipe went down through a hole and into the stove.

Now that the pipe is gone, it has exposed a bunch of insulation, and the insulation has fallen into the stove.

I'm unsure how to proceed, I don't know what the pipe is called or anything here is a photo of the issue.

[image]

Comment: it's called an oven .... pipe went down through a hole and into the oven

Comment: So “Oven Pipe”?

Comment: you did not ask what it is called ... you asked `Kenmore Stove / Range with range missing a pipe and insulation exposed?` ... the answer is `yes, the pipe is missing and the insulation is exposed`

Answer (score 2):

> I'm unsure how to proceed

First find the **make and model** number of the range.

Next, Use the internet to [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb) for the **make and model** of the range to see if you can find a service manual or user manual in order to see if there is a diagram of the parts. If you can find the name of the part then you will be able to search the internet for an [appliance parts](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=appliance%20parts&ia=web) web store.

If there is an experienced appliance repair shop in your area they may be able to tell you the name of the part or even order it for you if you can give them the **make and model** of the range.